# How do I convert parsed arguments to a variable that I can use in if statements?

Tags: python, parameters, argparse, variadic-functions

I'm using the tutorial imagenet image identification code from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/imagenet/classify_image.py

I have managed to get everything to work fine so far but I want to know how to get the arguments at the end as a list or string rather than parsed arguments so I can use normal if commands with them.

```
def main(_):
  maybe_download_and_extract()
  image = (FLAGS.image_file if FLAGS.image_file else
           os.path.join(FLAGS.model_dir, 'cropped_panda.jpg'))
  run_inference_on_image(image)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  # classify_image_graph_def.pb:
  #   Binary representation of the GraphDef protocol buffer.
  # imagenet_synset_to_human_label_map.txt:
  #   Map from synset ID to a human readable string.
  # imagenet_2012_challenge_label_map_proto.pbtxt:
  #   Text representation of a protocol buffer mapping a label to synset ID.
  parser.add_argument(
      '--model_dir',
      type=str,
      default='/tmp/imagenet',
      help="""\
      Path to classify_image_graph_def.pb,
      imagenet_synset_to_human_label_map.txt, and
      imagenet_2012_challenge_label_map_proto.pbtxt.\
      """
  )
  parser.add_argument(
      '--image_file',
      type=str,
      default='',
      help='Absolute path to image file.'
  )
  parser.add_argument(
      '--num_top_predictions',
      type=int,
      default=5,
      help='Display this many predictions.'
  )

  #how do i get a variable that i can interact with from this:
  FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with computer vision or the other tags you added. Please use the tags that describe the question itself, not the stuff you were doing when you stumbled upon the question. Tags are used by people here to find relevant questions to answer.

Comment: Do a `print(FLAGS)` and `pinrt(unparsed)` to see what the parser produced.  Attributes of `FLAGS` can be accessed by name, e.g. `FLAGS.model_dir` and `FLAGS.image_file`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a dictionary view of the arguments using `vars`.

An example from the argparse documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html):

```
>>> args = parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'BAR'])
>>> vars(args)
{'foo': 'BAR'}
```

So you should be able to do something like:

```
arg_dict = vars(FLAGS)
```

Comment: I don't want to get the arguments put in, I want the output. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean you want the output? You said you wanted to be able to convert parsed arguments to a variable.  In your code, you call parse_known_args and set the result to the FLAGS variable, so they are already in a variable. When you say you want to use it in if statements, can you give an example? Maybe that will help me understand the problem you are having.

Comment: You should be able to say `if FLAGS.image_file == '': ` or `if FLAGS.num_top_predictions > 5: ` or whatever you want to do when checking the arguments.